# How to Connect to Remote Realm Server with Realm Browser

Tags: realm, realm-browser

I have a Realm Object Server (v. 1.0) running on an Ubuntu server. Am I supposed to be able to connect to it via the [Realm Browser](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/realm-browser/id1007457278?mt=12) app?

Here is what I've tried.

**File** > **Open Sync URL...**

Then I enter my `realm` sync URL that I use in my iOS app. I also enter the username and password for one of my app users.
[image]

This sync URL and username/password work just fine in my app, but when I use them in the Realm Browser, I get a `Realm couldn't be opened` error:

[image]

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong? The Realm logs on my server don't show anything new when I make this attempt to connect.

Comment: I just tried doing that against a local instance of Realm Object Server, and it worked fine. Even if the login fails, there should at least be some kind of visible messages in your server's logs. Are you sure that IP address and port number are publicly accessible?

Comment: I can connect to local Realm servers, too. I'm certain my IP is accessible because right next to Realm Browser is the iOS Simulator running and working (and I can watch my app data update on my iOS device). Can you connect to a remote ROS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue. 
The solution was to download the new version of the Realm Browser (v2.0.1)
Here is the link:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/realm-browser/id1007457278?mt=12

Also if the username/password do not work please try using the Access Token, you should be able to find it under: "/etc/realm/".
Just use: "cat /etc/realm/admin_token.base64" it will print the token.

Comment: I got this to work. I had to upgrade my Realm Object Server to the `2.1` beta to get past a crash, but you helped me find the admin token which I didn't know about. Thank you! :)

Comment: I'm still having the problem. btw documentation is terrible, it has taken my whole day. anyone knows any proper tutorial and share the link I'll be glad a lot. (Note: I'm working it on macOS and trying to connect via localhost)